# Endless scrolling will_paginate is not working in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am following this [railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page) to integrate endless scrolling in my rails application. Here i am doing like this..

static_pages_controller.rb --

```
def home
  @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
end
```

home.html.erb --

```
<div id="posts_list" style="height:300px; overflow:scroll">
   <%= render :partial => "posts/posts" %>
   <p id="loading">Loading more page results...  </p>
</div>
```

Partial posts/posts ---

```
<% if @posts.any? %>
  <div id="postlist">
  <ul>
    <%= render partial: 'posts/posts_item', collection: @posts %>
  </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Partial posts/posts_item --

```
<li><%= posts_item.title %></li>
<li><%= posts_item.content %></li>
```

my static_pages/home.js.erb--

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :posts, :partial => @posts
  if @posts.total_pages > @posts.current_page
   page.call 'checkScroll'
  else
   page[:loading].hide
  end
```

and my assets/javascripts/endless_page.js --

```
var currentPage = 1;

 function checkScroll() {
   if (nearBottomOfPage()) {
    currentPage++;
    new Ajax.Request('/?page=' + currentPage, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get'});
   }    else {
     setTimeout("checkScroll()", 250);
  }
}

function nearBottomOfPage() {
  return scrollDistanceFromBottom() < 150;
}

function scrollDistanceFromBottom(argument) {
  return pageHeight() - (window.pageYOffset + self.innerHeight);  
}

function pageHeight() {
  return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight);
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', checkScroll);
```

But my endless scrolling is not working. I don't know where i am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Comment: Its not showing any error but it showing only initial 10 posts and when i scroll down then more post is not showing.

Comment: @FrederickCheung is there any better way to do this??

Comment: You need to dig into why this isn't working: is the javascript not triggering the ajax request, is the controller not returning the right  data, something else, etc.

Comment: Ya javascript is not triggering the ajax request. After scroll down, my next_page post items is not showing.